# How to split the script with | to the next line in r

Tags: r

I want to replace the column values based on a list of certain strings in the column. But the list is too long that I want to switch to the next line.
However, R will not take it.

```
####The test data file is data1
a <- runif (10)
b <- c("a;c", "a", "b", "c","a;b;c","a;d", "a;c", "a;b;c;d;e","e", "f")
c <- c(rep ("A-B", 4), rep("A_C", 6))
data1 <- data.frame (a, b, c)
data1 
####            a         b   c
####1  0.63360850       a;c A-B
####2  0.04681311         a A-B
####3  0.04743504         b A-B
####4  0.95342317         c A-B
####5  0.09054516     a;b;c A_C
####6  0.93139978       a;d A_C
####7  0.20558417       a;c A_C
####8  0.64131076 a;b;c;d;e A_C
####9  0.88136996         e A_C
####10 0.22000617         f A_C
list=c("a|b|c")
data1$b <- gsub(list, "[other]", data1$b)
####The ultimate goal example for the 1st line
####1  0.63360850       [other];[other] A-B
####But the list is actually too long, I have to move them into the next 
####line:
####E.g.:
list=c("a|
        b|
        c")
```

How to solve the change line problem of my list? I have more than just 3 strings, and each string is extremely long.
Can someone advice please? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `lst <- paste(c("a|",\n"b|",\n"c"), collapse="")`? (with actual newlines instead of my `\n` placeholders)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste`

```
my.list = paste(
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  sep ='|')
data1$b <- gsub(my.list, "[other]", data1$b)
```

Or another option is to remove the line breaks after defining the list as a single string:

```
my.list = 
"
a|
b|
c
"
my.list = gsub("\\n", "", my.list)
```

Comment: It works very well~ Thank you so much for the hints!